# rtorrent's session info in Python

Tags: python, bittorrent

I'd like to get some basic info about rtorrent's torrents. I assume the only way is to read files from rtorrent's session directory.

How would I do that in Python? Which encoding should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rtorrent has an [XML-RPC interface](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentXMLRPCGuide) which you can use with pythons [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html).

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I can successfully connect (`<ServerProxy for 127.0.0.1:5000/RPC2>`), but I'm getting `httplib.BadStatusLine: ''` exception when calling any of the methods (including `system.listMethods()`). Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I have never used this interface so I can't really help you with that :(

Comment: @Rainbow: open a new question with your problem or restructure this one if it has not been answered.